# Trying to Create a File from Blob but the Output file has Invalid Size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, blob

I am creating a canvas to rotate an image and creating a blob. But I need it as a file to upload it to server.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            // returning an error
            if (!blob) {
                reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
                return;
            }
            // blob.name = fileName;
            // creating a Object URL representing the Blob object given
            const rotatedImageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            resolve(rotatedImageUrl);
        }, 'image/jpeg');
    });
```

I am trying to create a file from the blob . I'm able to create it by using this snippet.

```
const rotatedFile = new File([img], originalFile.name, {
        type: originalFile.type,
    });
```

But the problem is generated file size is only 58 byte.

```
lastModified: 1644577677380
lastModifiedDate: Fri Feb 11 2022 17:07:57 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time) {}
name: "IMG_4792.JPG"
size: 58
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

I think the image is corrupted somehow.
Initially I thought canvas is somehow corrupting my image but I have also tried to create a file from an uploaded file converted to blob. That also gave me the same output. File size is not correct.

```
const file = e.target.files[0];
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
const generatedFile = new File([blobUrl], 'untitled', {
            type: file.type,
        });
```

Is there any solution? How can I properly create the file from the blob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using the `createObjectURL` ?

You should resolve the `blob` directly `resolve(blob);` and then the file will correctly represent the image, instead of representing the `objectURL`.

---

What you are seeing is the length of the generated url. Something like `"blob:https://........'`